# What to wear to an interview for a food services business?

Tags: interviewing, dress-code

I'm prepping for an interview at a small, well-known food business, more upscale (e.g. food sourcing / ingredients, pricing) than, say, McDonald's or Chipotle, but not like a fancy steakhouse or sushi restaurant.  So, something in between casual and premium.  What should I wear to the interview?  I have thought that wearing a suit, like I typically do for finance and tech interviews, would make me look a bit stiff and undesirable, but I'm afraid of dressing down too much.  I am thinking shirt, tie, pants, and dress shoes.

The job description is food prep, customer service at the tables, and cleaning.

Comment: You can't really go wrong with the outfit described. Although I'd wear more sesible shoes, thats just because I'm saving the dress ones for my funeral

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a food prep position I would expect you to be wearing casual attire. Keep it professional though. Jeans and a T-shirt are out. Khaki's and a polo are fine. A dress shirt and maybe a tie if you want to make a very professional impression (like you listed.) A full suit would make me think that you were out of touch with what you were applying for. I certainly wouldn't not hire someone because they wore a suit, but it would not give the impression that they were going for either.

One additional thing to consider is the atmosphere of the location. If customers are expected to wear a tie, then you probably need to too for the interview.

Comment: @user101435 Probably not. How upscale is the place? I didn't put that in my answer but you should definately adjust for that. If customers need a tie, then you do for the interview. Do you have kitchen shoes? If not wearing dress shoes then I suggest wearing something that demonstrates you are ready to work. I usually wear my boots. The fact that they are a bit greasy just means I've done this before.

Comment: @user101435 Its hard to say from price and concept alone. Unless it's a suit-and-tie fine dining joint you sound good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Get a glimpse of what people in your position will be wearing, and then try and dress at the same level or slightly higher.

If the people in the position wear dress slacks, a white shirt and a tie. Then wear that. Do so even if they wear a specific color shirt or a specific color tie and you don't have those colors.  It can't hurt if they can look at you and see you are willing to dress that way.

If they wear a coat, then try a similar look.

Don't forget the shoes.

If the look is blue jeans, and a company shirt; then jeans is appropriate.

Comment: so a lot of food prep wear provided uniforms.  If someone showed up to an interview in a chef's coat it wouldn't be *wrong*, but it also wouldn't be right.